# How to select the version to install when using dnf in Rhel 8?

Tags: node.js, rhel8, dnf

I want to install nodejs 18 using the DNF installer, but the default is set to stream 10. How can I change it to select version 18 when installing?

Commands used:

```
sudo dnf module install nodejs
sudo dnf module install nodejs-18
sudo dnf module install nodejs@18
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Tried to install nodejs 18, but when I used the following command:

```
sudo dnf module install nodejs
```

Only nodejs 10 is installing.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check available node versions on your server.

```
dnf module list nodejs
```

You can view the enabled node version with [e]. Now you need to reset your node version

```
dnf module reset nodejs
```

After that, you can enable your preferred node version with this command.

```
dnf module enable nodejs:18
```